# SQL - Is Associative entity a weak entity?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am quite confused by the concepts of [Associative entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) and [weak entity](http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Weak_entity.html). Is the associative entity a weak entity? If not, is there any relation between these two concepts? just take the following database as an example:

- Student(**StudentID**,StudentName,...)
- Enroll(**StudentID***,**CourseID***)
- Course(**CourseID**,CourseName,...)

  1. Is the `Enroll` an entity? Yes, I think. It is an assoicative
     entity.
  2. Is it a weak entity? The definition of weak entity is: a
     Weak Entity is an entity that cannot be uniquely identified by its
     attributes alone; therefore, it must use a foreign key in
     conjunction with its attributes to create a primary key. In this
     case, `Enroll` doesn't have its attribute ( Am I right?), so
     according to the definition, it should be a weak entity. So is my
     logic right? is the associative entity also a weak entity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*I was digging for the answer to this question as well and here is my observation.*

**Associative entity**

If an entity is placed between two entities to break up a M:N relationship, then that's an associative entity. Since the associative entity does not have an existence of its own, it is actually a weak entity as well, but will always be called an associative entity.

*Therefor, the Enroll(StudentID,CourseID) entity is an associative entity.*

**Weak entity**

In simple terms, a weak (dependent) entity is an entity that exists to store multi-valued attributes of a strong entity. That is, it doesn't sit between two independent entities. Example of a weak entity will be multi-valued attributes like phone number or email address, for a *person* entity.

Ref:

[1] *https://www.quora.com/What-are-examples-of-a-weak-entity-and-a-strong-entity*

[2] *http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Weak_entity.html*

Answer (score -1):

Whether or not `Enroll` is weak in this example, because a hybrid key of (StudentID, CouseID) could exist that may or may not be unique. Can a `Student` be enrolled in a `Course` more than once? If yes, then `Enroll` is weak, because doing

```
SELECT * FROM Enroll where StudentID = X AND CourseID = Y
```

could return multiple results.

You're correct on the first part though, `Enroll` does act as an associative entity here, since you have Many `Student`s in Many `Course`s. So, in the case where a Student can't enroll in a course more than once, `Enroll` isn't weak (since it has unique pairings), but is still associative, since Student:Course would still be a many to many join.

e; The site you linked is explaining weak a little differently than I've seen it before, so in its example your current `Course` is weak. However, you could imagine a `Course` that also has a CourseName (Chemistry I) or CourseNumber (CHEM101) that could be unique, and thus you'd have an associative entity that isn't weak.

Comment: `So, in the case where a Student can't enroll in a course more than once, Enroll isn't weak (since it has unique pairings), but is still associative,` I read on many websites that, ASSOCIATIVE Exist between many to many, then how you could say here it act like ASSOCIATIVE ENTITY?